# Javascript Google Maps API, function returning undefined and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps API with js and I keep having this problem where LatLng from other functions is being returned as undefined

This is the function I am using:

```
function geocodeAddress(addr)
{
    gc.geocode(
    {
        address: addr
    }, function(results, status)
    {
        if (status === "OK")
        {
            console.log("Geocoding " + addr);
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lat() + " " + 
results[0].geometry.location.lng());

            return results[0].geometry.location;

        }
        else
        {
            alert("Geocode failed: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see when the if statement is true it should return the location of that result. The console.log() statement above correctly prints the lat and lng values of the location.

However this is in another function and the console.log() is printing them as undefined:

```
    var addr1 = prompt("Enter name of first 
location.");
    var addr2 = prompt("Enter name of second location.");

    var but7firstloc = geocodeAddress(addr1);
    var but7secondloc = geocodeAddress(addr2);

    console.log("first " + but7firstloc);
    console.log("second " + but7secondloc);

    var request =
    {
        origin: but7firstloc,
        destination: but7secondloc,
        travelMode: "DRIVING",
        provideRouteAlternatives: true
    };
```

I am getting the error "InvalidValueError: in property origin: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object; and not an Object", as well as the variables being printed as undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your geocodeAddress-function does not return anything. You return the coordinates within the callback of the gc.geoCode-function. That value is used nowhere.

What you will have to do is actually returning the value of your api-request.
This can be done using promises. The following code should work for you:

```
const geocodeAddress = async (addr) => {
let result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        gc.geocode({
                address: addr,
            }, 
        (results, status) => {
            if (status === "OK") {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                })
                resolve(results[0].geometry.location);
            } else {
                alert("Geocode failed: " + status);
                reject()
            }
        })
    })
    return result
}

var addr1 = prompt("Enter name of first location.");
var addr2 = prompt("Enter name of second location.");

var but7firstloc = geocodeAddress(addr1);
var but7secondloc = geocodeAddress(addr2);

console.log("first " + but7firstloc);
console.log("second " + but7secondloc);

var request =
{
    origin: but7firstloc,
    destination: but7secondloc,
    travelMode: "DRIVING",
    provideRouteAlternatives: true
};
```